# ContentView get picker selected value

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The problem I'm having is that the label in ContentPageView is not displaying the selected value like it would if I'm not using the ContentView. I tried different things but nothing seems to be working, any advice on what I might be missing?

**NOTE: Simplified code removing unnecessary parameters. This is a custom control that gets reused a lot that have more components not related to this issue on hand**

PickerContentView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Core.Views.Templates.PickerContentView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Picker x:Name="CustomPicker" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

PickerContentView.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test.Core.Views.Templates
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PickerContentView: ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(PickerContentView), string.Empty);
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IList), typeof(PickerContentView), default(IList));
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDisplayBindingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemDisplayBinding), typeof(string), typeof(PickerContentView), string.Empty);
        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem1), typeof(object), typeof(PickerContentView), default);

        public string Title
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(PickerContentView.TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(PickerContentView.TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get => (IList)GetValue(PickerContentView.ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(PickerContentView.ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public string ItemDisplayBinding
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(PickerContentView.ItemDisplayBindingProperty);
            set => SetValue(PickerContentView.ItemDisplayBindingProperty, value);
        }

        public object SelectedItem1
        {
            get => GetValue(PickerContentView.SelectedItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(PickerContentView.SelectedItemProperty, value);
        }

        public PickerContentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == TitleProperty.PropertyName)
                CustomPicker.Title = Title;
            if (propertyName == ItemsSourceProperty.PropertyName)
                CustomPicker.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
            if (propertyName == ItemDisplayBindingProperty.PropertyName)
                CustomPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding(ItemDisplayBinding);
            if (propertyName == SelectedItemProperty.PropertyName)
                CustomPicker.SelectedItem = SelectedItem1;
        }
    }
}
```

ContentPageView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModelBase="clr-Test.Core.ViewModels.Base;assembly=Test.Core"
             xmlns:templates="clr-Test.Core.Views.Templates;assembly=Test.Core"
             x:Class="Test.Core.Views.ContentPage"
             viewModelBase:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             Title="Test">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <templates:PickerContentView Title="Picker List"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding ListObjects}"
                                             ItemDisplayBinding="Name"
                                             SelectedItem1="{Binding CustomObject, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding CustomObject.Name}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ContentPageView.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test.Core.Views
{
    public partial class ContentPageView: ContentPage
    {
        public ContentPageView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ContentPageViewModel.cs

```
namespace Test.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IService _service;
        private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> _listObjects;
        private CustomObject _customObject;

        public ObservableCollection<CustomObject> ListObjects
        {
            get { return _listObjects; }
            set
            {
                _listObjects= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListObjects);
            }
        }

        public CustomObject CustomObject
        {
            get { return _customObject; }
            set
            {
                _customObject= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => CustomObject);
            }
        }

        public CustomPageViewModel(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            ListObjects= await _service.GetListObjectsAsync();
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you debug, what value do you see assigned to the internal Picker's `SelectedItem` Property? If you see appropriate value there and you still don't see it in the UI, then it would be a layout issue. If you don't see the proper value being set, it could be a binding issue. It could be binding being removed from the target when you explicitly try to set the bound property on the target

Comment: @zafar when I debug I can see the correct value on the internal picker. But when I check on the ContentPage the CustomObject is null

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `propertyChnaged` delegate for the bindable properties in your `PickerContentView`

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(SelectedItem1),
                                                                                        returnType: typeof(object),
                                                                                        declaringType: typeof(PickerContentView),
                                                                                        defaultValue: default,
                                                                                        propertyChanged: SelectedItem1Changed);

private static void SelectedItem1Changed(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var thisView = bindable as PickerContentView;
    thisView.CustomPicker.SelectedItem = newValue ;
}
```

Also looks like the binding seems to be wrong , SelectedItem should be found in the bound ItemsSource , in your case looks like you are assigning to a new object `CustomPageViewModel.CustomObject` as opposed to `CustomPageViewModel.ListObjects[n]` if the objects are different it wont probably work. Then in the `SelectedItem1Changed` would be like

```
private static void SelectedItem1Changed(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var thisView = bindable as PickerContentView;
    var temp = thisView.CustomPicker.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x == newObject);
    if(temp != null)
          thisView.CustomPicker.SelectedItem = temp ;
}
```

I suggest you add `SelectIndex` property to the `PickerContentView`

Comment: Tried this with no luck still. After this CustomObject is still null in my ContentPage